# z-index won't react under overflow:hidden/scroll

Tags: css

First time here, bear with me :) 
I've searched numerous times for an answer but nothing I've found actually solved my problem.

I have a div that is `overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;` nested in another div.
The nested div contains other div elements with images that are `transform: scale(2);` on hover.
Problem is- the items won't breach the "Overflow" definition and are cut by the containing div.

This is how it looks:
[Image is cut by div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoOG4.png)

Containing div CSS:

```
.CatPnl {
position: relative;
background-color: #8BB2C5;
padding: 8px 5px 0px 0px;
height: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
box-shadow: 2px 1px 4px 1px #053655 inset;}
```

Inside Element which is scalled up on hover:

```
.imgItem {
width: 49.6px;
height: 49.6px;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
margin: -3px 1px 1px 2px;}

.containdiv:hover> .imgItem {
 transform: scale(2);
z-index:9;
}
```

I've tried z-index on hover, it didn't help so far.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: from the W3C z-index explanation 

Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

so maybe try adding some "position: relative" to the .containdiv:hover > .imgitem

Comment: Please post your HTML.  Try creating a Jsfiddle/Codepen/etc as well.

Comment: Not sure if `position:relative` would break the `overflow:hidden`, but `position:absolute` inside a `position:relative` surely would.

Comment: @PhilipBroadhead Thanks. That is correct, but only when the nested item is "absolute" as it seems. Unfortunately I cannot use this type of position in that case.

Comment: @Lowkase - it will be ab issue since I'm using asp.net and C# to create this page. This is not a simple HTML that I can simply paste in.

Comment: @turbopipp - You're correct, though I cannot use it in this case since the elements should be aligned to each other.

Comment: @Sagi Take the computed HTML output and use it in your example, not the source.

Answer (score 2):

Because the container is positioned (`position: relative;`) all elements within it will be positioned based on that context. Essentially, the position relative is creating a layer that it's children will live within. No matter how high of a z-index you apply to a child, it will never extend beyond the bounds of that layer.

To illustrate, I've created a fiddle that shows how it *can* work, though this is not a direct answer to your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/gzywzkep/

The problem in my fiddle is that I have to use `position: absolute` on the child node, so it pulls it out of its context an into a new layer, which kind of causes it to overlap the other elements. Note that the container element doesn't have any `position` property applied.

While this isn't a complete answer, I wanted to share so you could perhaps work out a solution based on it.

Comment: Thanks!
I can see that removing the `position: relative;` from the containing div does the trick indeed, but adding an absolute position to the elements nested in that div is an issue, since they all overlap each other that way.
I won't be able to set up position for each, since these are created dynamically.

Comment: Yeah, no prob. I see no reason why you couldn't add a simple single line of JavaScript that attaches an event listener to the resize/orientation events which merely calculates the outer height of the divs and adjusts the CSS style position on them. I realize you're trying to accomplish this with CSS only, so I don't want to dissuade you. Take this answer as a starting point and see if you mess around until you achieve it. You might even be able to get away with only scaling such that it doesn't extend past the container's padding or trying an alternative approach instead of scaling.